# A more generic py functionto cycle over datatable

Tags: python

I would like to generalize the following function to arbitrary # conditions for the control *&* arbitrary # of vectors for the appending:

```
def cycle(x,y,cond1, cond2, dtable):
    for row in dtable:
        if row[0] == cond1 and row[1] != cond2:
            x.append(row[1])
            y.append(row[2])
```

Maybe someone already did this ...

Thanks in advance,
Regards
Gian

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure about the object types you're handling, neither what are you trying to do

```py
def cycle(vectors, conditions, dtable):
    for row in dtable:
        if set(conditions) <= set(row): 
             # check if conditions is subset of row. 
             # If they must match you can simply use `conditions == row`. 
             for idx, vector in enumerate(vectors):
                   vector.append(row[idx + 1])
```

Note: I assumed that the row object is a List of string type. In case of a list of Cell Object you should probably do something like:

```py
def cycle(vectors, conditions, dtable):
    for row in dtable:
        cell_names = [cell.__str__() for cell in row]
        if set(conditions) <= set(cell_names): 
             for idx, vector in enumerate(vectors):
                   vector.append(row[idx + 1])
```